# Accept Content-Type:text/json request in Minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I am currently using .NET8 and Minimal API to handle requests. Everything works perfectly when a request has a header with the value `Content-Type: application/json`. However, when the 'Content-Type' is set to 'text/json', the API returns an HTTP code 415 error.

I am wondering how I can configure my Minimal API to accept requests with the 'Content-Type' set to 'text/json'?"

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue we should use `.Accepts(typeof(Something), "text/json")` after `.MapPost` or `.MapXXX` method.